# Copying set of specific columns between Pandas dfs where specific values match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am sure this is going to be a 'doh' moment, but I am having a difficult time trying to copy a set of columns between dataframes where the value of a specific column in df1 is also found in df2.

A simplified version of df1 looks like this:
[image: df1]

A simplified version of df2 looks like this:
[image: df2]

From here I'm building a list of columns (cols) that does not include the 'p_people_id' field from df1 and creating those fields in df2 and assigning a nan value.
cols=[image: columns from df1 != p_people_id]
After which df2 looks like this:
[image: df2 w appended cols]
Working with these dfs I'm trying to look find all instances where df2.a_people_id == df1.p_people_id and assign the values of df1[cols] to the df2 instance.

Finding the instance using .loc is simple enough.  I've managed to be able to select the cols I want to target using .loc as well

```
df2.loc[df2['a_people_id']==df1['p_people_id'][0],np.array(cols)]
```

This works fine and returns: [image]

But, if I try something like this to set/assign those specific columns where the id field in df1 matches the id field in df2:

```
df2.loc[df2['a_people_id']==df1['p_people_id'][0],np.array(cols)]=df1.loc[df1['p_people_id']==df1['p_people_id'][0],np.array(cols)]
```

Nothing happens and I'm not sure why. [image: df2 assignment results]

I've attempted to utilize .ix, .loc, .iloc, .where, .select, .set in various ways, but this has to be one of those areas where I'm "just not doin it right."  I can post other examples where I've managed to get the syntax right to find [cols] where the specific id matches and no error or 'view vs copy' warning is printed, but no assignment happens either.  Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, I think you're looking for a join operation.

In particular, this statement in your description:

```
df2.loc[df2['a_people_id']==df1['p_people_id'][0],np.array(cols)]
```

Means "look in `df2` for all rows where `p_people_id` matches the first `p_people_id` and for those rows, select the `cols` columns.

This produces a set of rows and a columns (6 in your example, all containing NA's) and, if I get things correctly, you then want to put those 6 lines together with the corresponding line in df1, plus do that for all `p_people_id` in `df1`.

If my assumption above is correct, then this can be done with a simple join. Like so:

```
pd.merge(left=df1, left_on="p_people_id",
         right=df2, right_on="p_people_id")
```

If there are 1000 different p_people_id in df1 and each of them had 6 lines in df2, the above statement would produce a dataframe with 6000 rows.

You can then select the desired columns in the result.

Comment: This looks like it does exactly what I was looking for with the exception of a little duplication, but that's a minimal problem that I can solve after joining the dfs.  Thank you!